# Number of triangles involving any two nodes

Tags: algorithm, numpy, graph, theano

Let's say I have an adjacency matrix **A** that represents an unweighted, undirected graph.

I would like to compute **B**, where **B**[*i*][*j*] is the number of closed triangles that include nodes *i* and *j*.

Is there a way to compute **B** from **A** using just linear algebra?  I'd like to implement this in theano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that `i` and `j` are adjacent to each other. Then, the number of triangles that contain both is the number of other vertices `k` that are connected to both of them. I.e.

```
B_i,j = Sum_k (if A_i,k=1 and A_k,j=1 then 1 else 0)
```

This assumes that the diagonal of the adjacency matrix is 0. The boolean expression can be converted to a single product because we use only 0 and 1:

```
B_i,j = Sum_k A_i,k * A_k,j
```

This looks pretty much like matrix multiplication and indeed it is:

```
B = A^2
```

However, we are still under the assumption that `i` and `j` are connected. To integrate this assumption into the final formula, we just have to multiply each component of `B` by the according entry of the adjacency matrix. This sets all entries to zero where `i` and `j` are not connected. So the final formula is:

```
B = (A^2) * A,
```

where `^2` is the matrix product with itself and `*` is component-wise multiplication.

Comment: Brilliant!  I checked this on a few toy examples and it worked out.  Thank you for writing it up so clearly.